# Badly coded module - how to explain this to other stakeholders

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, third-party-module, code-analysis

A client wants to integrate with a 3rd party that already have a freely available module. The only issue is the code in the module is pretty bad so I don't want to integrate it but the other stakeholders e.g. PM, Boss man and the client are struggling to understand why.

The module doesn't work out the box on vanilla magento but im sure a few fixes here and there will fix those issues - my main problem is the state of the code in the module which is always a difficult thing to convey to the stakeholders.

My question - what is the best way to communicate that the modules code is bad and full of code smells and bad practices so I don't want to integrate it to the stakeholders?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about Magento coding directly, but more about collaboration, work ethics and work floor policies. I would suggest to [post your question on Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I agree this is probably off topic for the focus we want to keep here on Magento SE.  That said, Tom, you may want to check out http://triplecheck.io which runs code quality analysis using PHP Code Sniffer etc coding best practices against the most popular plug-ins to score their quality objectively.  They may not have the specific extensions you're reviewing in their database however, and if not, you can upload the extension to http://judge.nr-apps.com/ and it will run a similar analysis for you in real time.

Comment: Hi Bryan & 7ochem - yeah no worries close the question if need be - thats for all the input. Yes I did find triplecheck but unfortunately the modules im referencing isn't in there - i will check out the other site though. Thankyou

Comment: If you want to convince your business stakeholders of a good reason WHY you would prefer to use higher quality code, you need to translate that into a tangible Business Impact.  A few ideas you may want to use : 1) Poor code quality generally results in lower performance, which decreases conversions and sales. 2) Poor code quality generally means the developers did not apply security best practices either potentially making you site more vulnerable to hackers. 3) Poor code quality will make it harder to patch & update because that code is more likely to break after applying the patch.

Answer (score 0):

This is asked often and the main barrier you need to climb here is understanding how other parts of organisation think and what are their goals. One thing that is hard to get is that *code quality* in itself does not have any value. Code quality is only valuable in code that is worth to maintain. If it is worth to maintain needs to be tested and testing in terms of business is not testing wether code has quality but instead does it has value in terms of making business.

1. code quality != business quality and that's why business deciders struggle to understand you
2. if you can get this running as it is with minimal effort and it works and does not have security issues then this is often enough to test the concept . test if something is valuable to business with proven cost (free code + your implementation time + whatever extra)
3. if it works and concept is proven that the feature is beneficial then you can improve the code or see alternatives later cause then it is proven that there is a value in this feature that can be compared against the cost of other alternatives or skipped completely
4. if it is really bad then you can explain  and show how costly this is to implement, maintain or change in the future or what security risks it brings to business owner. If those costs are bigger than the estimated value from a feature then they understand why

Answer (score 0):

simple:

> if you say that bicycle is bad, it means nothing. if you say that
>   bicycle has no wheels - ok now i understand the problem.

1. you see security holes?
2. trashes mysql with some heavy queries?
3. code loops and cpu load, memory leaks?

lol if your boss will dictate you to ruin his business - go ahead. no questions asked...
or you have to show some evidences.